# Xcode 7.1 not linking from /usr/local/lib library

Tags: c, xcode, swift

I am building a Swift command-line application with references to a third party library (netcdf) in /usr/local/lib. I have a bridging header in the project and when making the appropriate calls, there are no errors. So I'm fairly confident that the #include  is being found in the bridging file.

In Build Settings, I have added /usr/local/lib to Library Search Paths and -lnetcdf to Other Linker Flags.

However I am seeing a link failure. Specifically I am seeing an `undefined symbols` message. Looking at the ld command shown when I click on the error, I can see that -L/usr/local/lib is there. However the -lnetcdf is not.

What else do I have to do to get the -l into the link command?

Answer (score 0):

After three hours of trying to resolve this, I eventually thought 'stuff it' and spent about 15 mins writing a Makefile.

```
CLIBS=-lnetcdf
SWFILES=main.swift NCUtil.swift
SWIMPORT=-import-objc-header ../GSIP-Bridging-Header.h
SWIFTLIB=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx
SLIBS=-lSystem -lobjc

GSIP: main.o NCUtil.o
    ld $^ -arch x86_64 -L $(SWIFTLIB) $(SLIBS) $(CLIBS) -rpath $(SWIFTLIB) -macosx_version_min 10.10 -no_objc_category_merging -o $@

%.o: %.swift
    swiftc -c $(SWFILES) -target x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 -I /usr/local/include -I /usr/include $(SWIMPORT) -module-name=GSIP

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o GSIP
```

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact another solution. Using the Finder menu to `Go -> Go to Folder`, go to the directory where the dylib is located. Then from Finder, drop and drag the dylib into your project. Probably a wise idea to use a reference rather than make a copy of the file.

This resolved all my link errors!